# The `last-command' variable in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote a snippet to copy previous line to point,if I repeat the command,it copy more previous line. It's here:

```
    (defun my-copy-line (num)
      "copy lines"
      (interactive "p")
      (save-excursion
        (move-end-of-line 1)
        (push-mark)
        (move-beginning-of-line num)
        (kill-ring-save (point) (mark))))


(defvar copy-line-num 1)
(defun my-copy-line-here (num)
  "copy line ahead here"
  (interactive "p")
  (if (eq this-command last-command)
      (setq copy-line-num (+ copy-line-num num)) ;count num lines up
    (setq copy-line-default 1))
  (save-excursion
    (save-excursion                     ;make current line blank
      (move-beginning-of-line 1)
      (push-mark)
      (move-end-of-line 1)
      (kill-region (point) (mark)))     ;不用kill-line,以免删除空白行
    (push-mark)
    (previous-line copy-line-num)
    (my-copy-line 1)
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (yank))
  (setq this-command 'my-copy-line-here))
```

I intended to yank previous line to override current line.If I repeat `my-copy-line-here`,I'll yank the 2th previous line,this is accomplished by the test `(if (eq this-command last-command)`.But it failed ,Because every time after executing `my-copy-line-here`,it sets the `last-command` to `yank`,instead `my-copy-line-here`.I just can't figure out what's going on.I need your help.

Comment: Hi, you should consider marking some answers to your previous questions as "Accepted" so others will be more inclined to help you.  Adjudicating the correctness of answers is part of how everyone gives back to the SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-y (yank-pop) works similarly, pasting previous copied lines on repeated calls. Checking its sources, I see two differences with yours:

```
; explicit check for yank 
(if (not (eq last-command 'yank))

; setting this command
(setq this-command 'yank)
```

Perhaps one or both of these together can be useful. Set `this-command` after calling `yank` maybe?

Comment: Your method worked out,thank you. But actually,which really confused me is when to explicitly set `this-command` variable? because when you return from some command,Emacs automatically set it,it seems not to apply to my case.

Comment: I found this in Elisp Manual. `    Some commands set this variable during their execution, as a flag for whatever command runs next.  In particular, the functions for killing text set `this-command' to `kill-region' so that any kill commands immediately following will know to append the killed text to the previous kill.` I think `yank` is just belongs to this type.